# Can you help me identify this garnish?

Tags: food-identification, plating

I recently visited a restaurant and was served this gorgeous lemon meringue tart. Can you help me identify which plant this green garnish belongs to?
[image: The garnish in question]

Comment: It really helps with plant identification if you can get a clear picture of the leaf.  But you did manage to capture the little curly bit coming off the side of the stem, suggesting that it's some sort of climbing vine (such as pea shoots, like Chris mentioned)

Comment: @Joe that was what caught my attention, then the leaf shape looks about right and the stems lighter than the leaves. It all looks a little pale but I reckon that's the style of the photo

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The picture isn't from the best angle for identification, though it's very pretty, but it looks to be a pea shoot ([picture](https://www.greatbritishchefs.com/ingredients/pea-shoot-recipes)).

These are common garnishes for savoury dishes, but much less common for sweet dishes, though [not completely unknown (also a lemon recipe)](https://www.runningtothekitchen.com/sweet-pea-lemon-crepe-cake/).